# Ruby JSON Schema Validator Not Returning Expected Result

Tags: json, ruby, validation, jsonschema

I am using the JSON schema validator gem to verify a response is coming back with expected keys and value types. My data should be coming back in the following JSON format:

```
{
    "hierarchies": [
        {
            "hierarchyId": "123ABC456DEF789",
            "depth": 1,
            "hierarchyNodes": [
                {
                    "nodeId": "ANID123456FORNODE789",
                    "id": "12345678"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- "hierarchies" can be an array of 0..N elements
- "hierarchyNodes" can also be an array of 0..N elements

My current schema is the following (I am missing the node arrays currently):

```
schema = {
  '$schema' => 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    hierarchies: {
      type: 'array',
      properties: {
        object_items: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            hierarchyId: { type: 'string' },
            depth: { type: 'integer' }
          },
          required: [:hierarchyId, :depth],
          additionalProperties: false
        }
      },
      required: [:object_items]
    }
  },
  required: [:hierarchies]
}
```

For some reason, the following returns true when the expected result should be false for all of these:

> 0> JSON::Validator.validate(schema, {hierarchies: [{}] })
>   => true
>
> 0> JSON::Validator.validate(schema, {hierarchies: [{hierarchyId: 'hi', depth: 1, something: 'hey'}] })
>   => true
>
> 0> JSON::Validator.validate(schema, {x: [{a: 'something'}] })
>   => true

An expected True result would have the following schema, and only this schema:

> JSON::Validator.validate(schema, {hierarchies: [{hierarchyId: 'id',
>   depth: 1}] })

Can someone let me know where i have gone wrong with setting up the validation schema?

Thanks!

Comment: Try testing with a tool like this [JSON Schema Validator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net). It's found errors with your example even with the missing `,` added.

Comment: @tadman, I see where the comma was missing and i have added it in. That was a copy error. I will check out that site and see if i can find an answer.

Comment: I'm still getting an invalid result

Comment: Have you tried using a generator like [this one](https://jsonschema.net/#/editor) to produce a baseline reference?

Comment: @tadman, I will give this a try to create an accurate base. I noticed the generator CAN create the "required" attribute and i think that is half of my problem. I will take another stab at this. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion provided by @tadman, I came upon this solution:

```
schema = {
  '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#',
  'properties': {
    'hierarchies': {
      'additionalItems': false,
      'items': {
        'additionalItems': false,
        'properties': {
          'depth': { 'type': 'integer' },
          'hierarchyId': { 'type': 'string' },
          'hierarchyNodes': {
            'additionalItems': false,
            'items': {
              'additionalItems': false,
              'properties': {
                'id': { 'type': 'string' },
                'nodeId': { 'type': 'string' }
              },
              'required': ['nodeId', 'id'],
              'type': 'object'
            },
            'type': 'array'
          }
        },
        'required': ['hierarchyId', 'depth', 'hierarchyNodes'],
        'type': 'object'
      },
      'type': 'array'
    }
  },
  'required': ['hierarchies'],
  'type': 'object'
}
```

Comment: `additionalItems` has no effect in this schema.  `additionaltems` only applies when `items` is an array.  Otherwise, it looks good!

Comment: @Jason, thanks for the comment. While unnecessary, it shouldn't hurt to leave `additionalItems` in, correct? And is there a way to have this schema fail if any more properties exist in the json response being validated?

Comment: It doesn't hurt in the sense that leaving it will not change the validation behavior.  But, I can't imagine why you would want to have something in your schema that is used incorrectly and does nothing.

Comment: You can add `"additionalProperties": false` to you object schemas and validation will fail when the JSON has extra properties.  However, I always recommend that it is better to simply ignore these properties instead of forbidding them.

Comment: I would like the validation to fail if the JSON has any extra properties other than what is specifically required in the schema. We want to know if anything has been added over time since this is coming from a service used by external areas who expect a very specific response.